# JS: How does event.touches property work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, touches

I don't understand how to use the event.touches property. For example to get the number of fingers on a iPad/iPhone you should use

```
event.touches.length
```

Then why is this example code not working?

```
$('.image').bind('touchstart', function(event) {
  alert(event.touches.length);
});
```

But this is working:

```
$('.image').bind('touchstart', function() {
  alert(event.touches.length);
});
```

Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the second case, you're falling back on the browser's global (and raw) `event` object rather than the jQuery-specific one (on browsers that support a global `event`, not all do — Firefox doesn't, for instance — because it's a Microsoft thing only some others have copied).

It sounds like jQuery isn't passing the `touches` property on in its custom event object. As described in the [event object's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), you can use `event.originalEvent` in your first example to access the "special properties" it has while still getting the benefits of the jQuery normalized event object, e.g.:

```
$('.image').bind('touchstart', function(event) {
  alert(event.originalEvent.touches.length);
});
```

...or you can tell jQuery to copy that property over by doing this once at the beginning of your script:

```
jQuery.event.props.push("touches");
```

...whereupon your first example should start working.

---

Side note: If you're not using [jQuery Touch](http://jqtouch.com/), you might look at it. My guess is that in addition to the other things it does, it adds the `touches` property as shown above (but that's just a guess).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now I understand and it's working. By the way, I'm using jQTouch, so apparently it doesn't add the touches property.

Comment: @Tina: Glad that helped. Wow, that's really surprising about jQTouch not adding it!