# Angular Slider Touch not working with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch, angularjs-directive, uislider

I am using the following directive in my application

https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider

It's all working ok apart from touch support when I'm trying to drag the sliders across the screen. Touch works on the examples given but not on my application. I have checked I'm using the same version of angular etc.

My code:
filter.js (Controller)

```
$scope.lower_price_bound = 50;
$scope.upper_price_bound = 3000;
```

html

```
<slider floor="10" ceiling="3000" ng-model-low="lower_price_bound" ng-model-high="upper_price_bound"></slider>
```

Do I need to add anything to get touch support for mobile devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still experiencing this issue, this might help: [JS: How does event.touches property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965538/js-how-does-event-touches-property-work)  "It sounds like jQuery isn't passing the touches property on in its custom event object."

This fixed it for me.  Change this:

```
onMove = function (event) {
              var eventX, newOffset, newPercent, newValue;
              eventX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
              ...
```

to

```
 onMove = function () {
              var eventX, newOffset, newPercent, newValue;
              eventX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
              ...
```

(line 227 on my version of angular-slider.js)

Comment: Thanks! I don't get why you omit the "var" though?

Comment: Delos, check out my answer below for a Firefox solve.

Answer (score 1):

From the code of the slider directive it seems that you don't need to do anything special to support touch events. I have assembled a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qUwPh) with the code you provide and everything is working as expected. I have tested it with chrome on my Sony xperia phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The example you have provided also works on my mobile. I have come to the conclusion it is my app that somehow conflicts with the touch support. I'm using a MEAN stack and I even created an app with just a slider and I'm still getting no touch support - the pointer does highlight on touch but there is no drag.

Comment: Is there anyway jquery/another lib could be causing a conflict here?

Comment: Two common conflicts I can think of. 1/ you have an overflow on your page and the browser can't tell if you want to move the page around or start the slider drag (try to put css overflow:hidden on the body tag). 2/ Somewhere in the code there is an event handler on touchmove that stops the propagation of the dom event. But this one will be more difficult to spot.

Comment: Thanks again. I finally found out what was causing the issue. For some reason if I loaded jquery before the slider there was a conflict. Loading it after the slider and it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Loading it after the slider would imply that you're using jqLite with angular for the angular-slider, which causes other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ryan's fix above, I managed to get my sliders working as expected. However, as mentioned in the comments, it did break Firefox for me as well. In order to fix the Firefox issues, the following changes are also needed inside of angular-slider.js:

**Line 79:**

Change:

```
sliderDirective = function($timeout) {
```

By adding a `$window` paramater:

```
sliderDirective = function($timeout, $window) {
```

**Line 227:**

Change:

```
onMove = function () {
    var eventX, newOffset, newPercent, newValue;
    eventX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
    ...
```

By adding a `customEvent` parameter to the `onMove()` function and assigning your own `event` variable (`myEvent`):

```
onMove = function(customEvent) {
    var eventX, newOffset, newPercent, newValue,
        myEvent = $window.event || customEvent;

    eventX = myEvent.clientX || myEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    ...
```

This way, the function will either use the native `window.event` variable (which exists in Firefox), or the one provided by the library.

**Line 317:**
Lastly, update the dependency declaration by changing:

```
qualifiedDirectiveDefinition = ['$timeout', sliderDirective];
```

to include `$window`

```
qualifiedDirectiveDefinition = ['$timeout', '$window', sliderDirective];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try **[ng-slider](https://github.com/darul75/ng-slider)**

It allows touch devices to click on the toggle instead of dragging (which is highly difficult on touch devices).

It offers a lot more features and configuration as well.